# LESS file path invalid after migration of Magento

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have migrated a Magento site (v 2.4.6-p3) to a another server (same version) and noted two CSS less files are not getting loaded properly. The file urls are invaild.In browser console I see  errors similar to follwing.

Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/static/version1710602546/_cache/hRadios.less' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

When the URL https://example.com/static/version1710602546/_cache/hRadios.less checked separately, it shows this error.

```
Requested path '_cache/hRadios.less' is wrong.
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]
</pre>
```

I have tried clearing caches, static content redeployment, removed contents of folders generated,var/cache, pub/static/_cache , set full file permissions to folders, issue retains same.

Can someone please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil